# How magento2 extension available in composer

Tags: magento2, composer

We have planning to submit a magento2 extension into Magento marketplace. Currently extension hosted in GitHub private repository.

After successful approval from "Magento marketplace" (Marketing and technical review), how that available via composer?

or "Magento marketplace" automatically synchronize extension into packagist.org ?

In order install extension available in composer, what are the steps need to do ?